# Ошибка : Сайт пока не может обработать этот запрос. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

Здравствуйте, пришла нужда создать удаленный php сервер:

арендовал сервер на Ubuntu 16.04 x64

установил lamp

В итоге на ип адресе открываеться html страница Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page.

Потом я добавил index.php содержание

`<?php echo '<p>Привет, мир!</p>'; ?>`

и при обращении на server_ip/index.php выдает

Страница недоступна
Сайт  server_ip пока не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: PHP файл в папке /var/www/html или в другой? Как реализован хостинг в вашей конфигурации? http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apache2

Comment: да я положил index.php туда /var/www/html      
help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apache2  я установил как написано тут

Comment: И htaccess в порядке, как надо?

Comment: вот его вообще нет, и я не знаю как его создать с нужной кодировкой в sublime text (notepad++ нет у меня mac)

Comment: Надо бы логи ошибок посмотреть, вариантов может быть много, вот тут есть некоторые советы https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/web-server/server-management/how-to-fix-http-error-code-500-internal-server-error/